# Many-To-Many with Azure Cosmos DB and Entity Framemewok Core CosmosDB

Tags: entity-framework-core, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.1

I'm using the nosql Azure Cosmos DB (Core SQL) with EF Core Cosmos 3.1.

I have a structure of packages and modules where :
TypeCar has 0...N TypeUser
TypeUser has 0...N TypeCar

I need to list TypeCars and TypeUsers, even if they have no children.

How shoud I structure my models ?
Should I store only list of IDS ? Duplicate objects in children ? Both ?

Answer (score 0):

For most of your reads:

If you need parent object and all or most children (All properties) then you should duplicate.

If you need parent object but occasionally need one or more children, then store a list of child IDs in the parent.

If you need parent object and all or most children (few properties) then you should store a list of child IDs plus the few child properties you need in the parent.

Your writes will also impact the option you choose.

More info can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data